# same nature,same will vs Qu'ran 23:89-92,21:22

Tags: tawheed

if there are two divine beings,and because they are all fully divine they have the same nature,wouldn't their wills always be in agreement since the will comes from the nature?

how then can Quran:23:89-92 and Quran 21:22 be true?

Comment: No  their wills must not necessary be aligned. Two superior beings can't co-exist as one would like to be the most superior.And alignment in such a case a kind flattery is needed.

Comment: You are talking here about dieties, something our brain can't understand. You can't admit that "because they are fully divine [...] their wills would always be in agreement", when you don't truly know what a diety is and how it works. One must here accept what comes from the Only Diety Allah that, unlike us, truly knows what a diety is and how it behaves

Comment: @Medi1Saif if two divine beings exist,they have all the properties of divinity and they will only the perfect good,so their wills would always be in alignment wouldn't it?humility is a perfection so they would get along perfectly?

Comment: @muslimpro56,I define diety as a necassery and perfect being.two gods wouldn't conflict because they have the same perfect nature,and thus always will the perfect in every scenario.this argument by the qu'ran is fallacious it seems to me.

Comment: Saying an argument of the Quran is fallacious while still supposing something completely out of your reach, while you seem like you understood the problem perfectly, and found the ultimate, undoubtable solution, is very egoistic and selfish, do you realize you're judging the saying of Allah, the creator ? Some more verses = "Allah certainly *knows and you do not know*" 16:74 "*or are you ˹just˺ saying about Allah what you do not know*?" 2:80 "Allah knows and you do not know." 2:216 "My Lord has only forbidden [...] *and attributing to Allah what you do not know.*" 7:33.

Answer (score 0):

Those verses are meant as a refutation to the common conceptions of polytheism, not two perfect divine beings.

The common polytheism of the Arabs is some gods control some things and other gods control other things and they do not necessarily have the same will. These gods are not necessarily perfect divine beings. There is a god of the sun and a god of the moon and so on. This is similar to Greek mythology and Hinduism.

Allah shows how this claim doesn't make sense by pointing to the uniformity and systematic nature of the universe. There is no disjoint. If there were multiple gods like this, the world would be chaotic as they would disagree and each would control one part in the way he wants.

That is why Allah says:

> Had there been within the heavens and earth gods besides Allah, they both would have been ruined. So exalted is Allah, Lord of the Throne, above what they describe. (21:22)

Meaning: If there were many gods as you claim, each controlling his own parts, it would have been clearly ruined as there would be no one system. But, we see a universe that is unified and works in cohesion. This does not point to multiple different gods controlling it.